# Can't save carrierwave image in test environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, carrierwave

I am having some issues with Rspec 3 and carrierwave saving an image to a specified test directory. I have been reading the docs but am constantly faced with

```
Failure/Error: @uploader.store!(File.open("#{Rails.root}/spec/fixtures/yp2.jpg"))
NoMethodError:
undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass
# ./spec/rails_helper.rb:73:in `store_dir'
```

A tmp path is created at

```
/spec/uploads/tmp/
```

But the image is not saved at the following as expected

```
/spec/uploads/animal_image/image/12
```

in my `rails_helper.rb` I have

```
# set test specific store directory 
if defined?(CarrierWave)
 CarrierWave::Uploader::Base.descendants.each do |klass|
  next if klass.anonymous?
   klass.class_eval do
    def cache_dir
     "#{Rails.root}/spec/support/uploads/tmp"
    end 

    def store_dir
     "#{Rails.root}/spec/support/uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
    end 
   end 
  end 
end
```

and my actual test

```
require 'rails_helper'
require 'carrierwave/test/matchers'

describe AnimalImage do 
 include CarrierWave::Test::Matchers

before(:each) do
 AnimalImageUploader.enable_processing = true
 @uploader = AnimalImageUploader.new(@animal, :image)
 @uploader.store!(File.open("#{Rails.root}/spec/fixtures/yp2.jpg"))
end

after(:each) do
 @uploader.remove!
 AnimalImageUploader.enable_processing = false
end

context 'Image Versions' do

 it 'should scale large_animal_image to 555 x 365 ' do
  expect(@uploader.large_animal_image).to have_dimensions(555, 365)
 end
end 
end
```

Does anyone have any ideas as to why this could be happening?

### Edit

Whilst doing some debugging I have captured the @uploader object from my spec

```
 <AnimalImageUploader:0x00000002dafa28 @model=nil, @mounted_as=:image
```

How do I set the model?

### Edit 2

So after taking the comments on board provided by @rossta I have managed to get the images to save in the correct place along with all versions of the image but now I just need to find a matcher that will tell me that the versions of each image are the correct dimensions

```
before(:each) do
 AnimalImageUploader.enable_processing = true
 file = File.open("#{Rails.root}/spec/fixtures/yp2.jpg")
 @animal = AnimalImage.create!(image: file)
 @uploader = AnimalImageUploader.new(@animal, :image)
 @uploader.store!
end
```

Answer (score 1):

In your test, `@animal` is the model, but you haven't set it's value to anything. Try creating an animal record or instantiating a stubbed version that respnds to methods like `id`:

```
before(:each) do
  AnimalImageUploader.enable_processing = true
  @animal = Animal.create!
  @uploader = AnimalImageUploader.new(@animal, :image)
  @uploader.store!(File.open("#{Rails.root}/spec/fixtures/yp2.jpg"))
end
```

Comment: ok getting close now, if i set '@animal = AnimalImage.create' @animal = `#<AnimalImageUploader:0x00000004313cc0 @model=#<AnimalImage id: nil, animal_id: nil, image: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>, @mounted_as=:image>` the test passes but theres nothing in the object ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "nothing in the object". I did notice from your comment that the `id` of your `AnimalImage` is nil which means it wasn't properly saved in the database. Check your validation and make sure the required values are set before creating.

Comment: thanks, images are now saving to the correct place, see my update in question to show how i got there..just need to find a matcher now to check the dimensions of each image type